# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value Error when reading json from txt file

Tags: python, json, file

I'm trying to read some data from a .txt file using JSON, but I'm getting the below error. I've tried various ways such as trying to fix the error, but that reads nothing.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: 
 Expecting value Error when reading json from txt file
```

Besides modifying the code, I've also tried converting my input file to JSON format.

An example of my data:

> `("TeamSoft is seeking an IT Support Specialist to join our client in Madison, WI.", {"entities":[ (1, 9, 'ORG'), (24, 45, 'JOB'), (68, 75, 'GPE'), (77, 79, 'GPE') ]}),`

Python:

```py
def readData(path):    
    lines = []
    inputfile=open(path, "r")
    for line in inputfile:
        line = json.loads(line)
        lines.append(line)
    return lines
```

I'd like to put this in a list so I can train my Spacy NER model from a file. When I tried reading it as text, it threw an error. One of the co-founders of Spacy told me to read it as json.

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid JSON; it has quite a few problems.

JSON does not have a tuple type, so the parentheses are invalid. You need to make them all arrays.

Also, all strings need to have double quotes; and you cannot end an array or object with a trailing comma.

```
[
    "TeamSoft is seeking an IT Support Specialist to join our client in Madison, WI.",
     {"entities": [ [1, 9, "ORG"], [24, 45, "JOB"], [68, 75, :"GPE"], [77, 79, "GPE"] ]}
]
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got a different error. My data now looks like the following: "We require an accountant with at least 5 years of experience.", {"entities":[ (14, 24, 'JOB'), (39, 46, 'DATE') ]}

Comment: But you still have parentheses and single quotes!

Comment: So I have to change the single quotes for the labels too. Sorry I didn't notice that.

Comment: I changed the single quotes to double quotes, but I am still getting the same error. My data now looks like this. "TeamSoft is seeking an IT Support Specialist to join our client in Madison, WI.", {"entities":[ (1, 9, "ORG"), (24, 45, "JOB"), (68, 75, "GPE"), (77, 79, "GPE") ]}

Comment: For the third time. You cannot have parentheses - `(...)` in JSON.

Comment: I did what you told me to do. I am now getting a new error telling me I need the comma. The error is the following: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter:

Comment: My data looks like this: ["We require an accountant with at least 5 years of experience.", {"entities":[ [14, 24, "JOB"], [39, 46, "DATE"] ]}]

Comment: When I add a comma, it gives me the previous error. json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 118 (char 117)